# Storage Access Framework in test app

Tags: android, testing, android-external-storage, storage-access-framework

I am using `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to grant my application write access to external storage (on Lollipop and Marshmallow).

But I would like write to external storage in test application. `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` uses system dialog so I cannot grant the permission during tests. I also tried to allow it in application and then use it in tests but it is not shared - application project and test project are different packages.

Does anybody know some workaround that might e.g. grant permission for whole external storage for test purpose? Maybe by changing some system property?

`adb shell setprop SOMEPROPERTY 1`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this commands for granting and revoking permissions

```
adb pm grant com.package.myapp android.permission.<PERMISSION>
adb pm revoke com.package.myapp android.permission.<PERMISSION>
```

Permissions for read/write external storage are

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Here is the link to video where it is explained: [Runtime Permissions in Android 6.0 Marshmallow (Android Development Patterns Ep 3)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8lUdPVSzDk).

Comment: Unfortunately this is only replacement for access to main external storage. I need access using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to secondary external storages and I need to test this functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Here as a workaround you can use **adb shell input keyevent** for checking grant permission checkbox.

Usage:

```
   adb shell input [text|keyevent]
   adb shell input text <string>
   adb shell input keyevent <event_code>
```

[More Details you can find here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

Comment: I need to grant the permission in test application. But I don't even know how to show the system "Open with" dialog in TEST application to be able to grant it, e.g. with this adb shell input...or manually. Do you have any example?